# Java libGDX tetris collisions

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I´m working on a Tetris game and I´ve started with the collision part. Currently the first line works fine, the collision does what it´s supposed to. When i get the the second line it stops working.. I´m still adding the rectangles to the array and nothing seems wrong in the code. I´ve been using the debugger a lot but i can´t find the problem. This is my first programming project i´ve ever done. Been learning java for about 3 months now so this is surely a noob problem. Here is my create and render method. Thank you for reading.

```
@Override
public void create () {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    blocks = new Array<Blocks>();
    boxes = new Array<Rectangle>();


    block = new Block();
}


@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, .2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    block.getRenderer().setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    block.draw();



    // Update
    block.drop(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    isFalling = true;


    Rectangle box = block.getBox();

    // Collision
    for(Rectangle r: boxes) {
        if(box.overlaps(r)) {
            isFalling = false;
            System.out.println("collision");
            block.setY(r.height);
            boxes.add(box);
            blocks.add(block);
            System.out.println("Block added. creating new block..");
            block = new Block();
            break;
        }
    }


    // Borders
    if(box.x < 0) box.x = 0;
    if(box.x > WIDTH - box.width) box.x = WIDTH - box.width;
    if(box.y < 0) {
        isFalling = false;
        System.out.println("not falling");
        box.y = 0;
        boxes.add(box);
        blocks.add(block);
        System.out.println("Block added. creating new block..");
        block = new Block();
    }


    // Controls
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.LEFT) && isFalling)
        block.stepLeft();
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.RIGHT) && isFalling)
        block.stepRight();
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.DOWN))
        block.setDown();

    for(Blocks b: blocks) {
        b.draw();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tetris blocks have discreet positions. Its game area is 20 rows high and 10 columns wide. There is probably no need for standard collision detection.

You can for example use a 2D array with boolean or integer values that represent presence of a square on a location:

```
int[][] squares = new int[20][10];
```

You can then use this information to determine if there is a collision:

- Rotation or movement should only be allowed if the resulting position from that action does not cause any of the squares to overlap with already present squares on game area and are inside the game area bounds (20 rows and 10 columns).
- If any square on a currently active block reaches bottom row or is in the same column and one row above a square already filled, then the block has reached its end destination.
- If when a block first appears on the screen some of its squares are already in occupied positions then it is game over.
- Etc.

I made a Tetris clone using libgdx a few years ago, check it out if you think it might help you. You can see some images [here](http://goranm.com/portfolio/suchyblocks) and get the source from [here](https://github.com/mrzli/suchyblocks).

Clarification: When I say block I mean a tetromino, the entire object that falls from the top. Each Tetris block contains four squares in various arrangements.

Comment: Nice Tetris game! looks good but.. I think I need to approach this problem the way I imagine it to work. Otherwise I will just copying someone else's code and that wont make me a better programmer. I´ve broken down my project into small problems, and each problem should get me closer to a finished game. Currently it´s the collision part I need to solve. But thanks again =)

Comment: @Sociopaten you don't need to use a different approach, you just need to think about the approach others used, instead of copying it. If you understand the approach, you may be able to use it (or a slightly changed version) for other problems to, if you just copy it, you won't be able to even use this approach a second time. In the Tetris case the `collision detection` is only somthing like checking if a cell, my tetris-object occupies and if it is allready occupied by others there is a collision.

Comment: @Sociopaten Please take into account that standard collision detection might cause problems in some situations, such as when you try to fit a square in one slot between two squares, or even in some more common cases - you might get a collision in situations when there should not be one. Besides, I didn't invented this approach - I think I stole it from somewhere :)

Comment: Yes. This makes much more sense to me now. Thanks, you have been verry helpful.